# Function to render notification React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a custom notification (toast). It's part of custom UI library and the component is as simple as

```
<Notification message="Success!" close={()=>console.log('Close notification')} />
```

I know I can place Notification component in some top level app component, usually called `index.js` or `App.js` and then `message` could be stored in some global store like redux, however I'm looking for a way to create some utility function to simply call `shawNotification` from whatever place in the app. NOTE - I wanna support not only React components (also places like sagas, redux actions etc.) so it cannot be as a hook. The ideal API would be:

```
showNotification('Success!', ()=>console.log('Close notification'));
```

And it would render a `Notification` component for 5 seconds. I cannot find any example of such functionality, would appreciate any help, could be even article links.

Comment: Can you use a library like react-hot-toast  https://react-hot-toast.com/ ? It makes toast messages easy and cans et custom timer

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Checkout [this link](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString). It exposes a `renderToString(reactNode)` function which parses the React Code to pure HTML string.

What you could do is, prerender it inside the body using this `renderToString`.

```
// notificationService.js
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import Notification from './Notification';

const notificationRoot = document.getElementById('notification-root');

const showNotification = (message, onClose) => {
  const notificationElement = (
    <Notification message={message} onClose={onClose} />
  );
  let notificationHtml = renderToString(notificationElement);
  document.body.appendChild(notificationHtml);
};

export default showNotification;
```

Or with the following:

```js
// notificationService.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Notification from './Notification';

const notificationRoot = document.getElementById('notification-root');

const showNotification = (message, onClose) => {
  const notificationElement = (
    <Notification message={message} onClose={onClose} />
  );

  ReactDOM.render(notificationElement, notificationRoot);
};

export default showNotification;
```

index.html

```html
<div id="notification-root"></div>
```

Another solution will be to use [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/).
You can customize it all you want using a CSS file and you can call the toasts like this:

```bash
npm i --save toastr
```

```js
import toastr from 'toastr';

toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')

toastr.success('Are you the 6 fingered man?')
```

Comment: Once you render a component to a string like in your 1st example, it is no longer a React component - just simple HTML. This means the onClose functionality will be lost.

Comment: Your second example unnecessarily requires modification to the HTML, and again does not support closing cleanly. Instead it would be best to render the `Notification` component conditionally somewhere near the top of the app, and just open/close it with a global state solution

Comment: So I tried both solutions. Like Brian mentioned the onClose is lost, which for some simple solution I'm fine. I have the solution number 1 working however that's not ideal since I wanna close the toast after 5 seconds and none of the useEffect is called since we use `renderToString`. 

The solution number 2 is not anything I could do since I don't wanna force the client apps to add `<div id="notification-root"></div>` or anything similar.

Comment: Although the second one works like a charm and close action works so the only bad part of it is that one when we need `<div id="notification-root"></div>`

Comment: Maybe try something like this?
`const notificationRoot = document.createElement('div');
notificationRoot.id = 'notification-root';

if(document){
   document.body.appendChild(notificationRoot);
  
}

...
ReactDOM.render(notificationElement, notificationRoot);

`